# Use favicon.ico based on skin

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, favicon

I have a application where i have two versions, Both these versions used different skin. My problem is I need to change favicon based on skin used.

In my application root folder there is only one favicon of one skin.

For 2nd favicon i used path in index.php like

```
<html>
<head> 
  <link href="images/skin2/favicon.ico" rel="SHORTCUT ICON"/>
</head>
</html>
```

And it render favicon of 2nd skin fine, but when i refresh page using Ctrl + F5 then favicon of 1st skin get rendered which is placed in root directory.

Please advise me some solution to solve this problem....

Comment: I'm confused. Is this a PHP problem or an ASP.NET problem?

Comment: This is a general problem.. my application has both files..Index.php is called using some url re-writing..

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some trick and it is working fine, sharing here may help others

```
<script>
var faviconFolderName = "skin3";
if(skinName == "skin1")
{
    faviconFolderName = "skin1";
}else if(skinName == "skin2"){
    faviconFolderName = "skin2";
}

$(window).load(function () {
    $('head').append('<link href="images/'+faviconFolderName+'/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox might be caching the favicon.

Try

1. Append a query string to the end of the favicon name

   `<link href="images/skin2/favicon.ico?v=2" rel="SHORTCUT ICON" />`
2. Check to make sure the favicon is accessible. Go to the URL and force a refresh.

   - `http://mydomain/images/skin2/favicon.ico`
   - Ctrl + F5
3. Rename the favicon file.

Comment: Hi Rowan.. i tried mentioned steps...
As in 1st step "?v=33304" is added to the url but favicon still changed to default one , here 3304 is build id number. Also 2nd skin favicon is accessible even after  Ctrl + F5 from URL "https://test.com/images/skin2/favicon.ico?v=33304"
3rd step- in this case i renamed it to 'favicon12' and it start showing blank image..

Answer (score 0):

Use url rewriting to retrieve favicon.ico from php or asp.net.

You can disable caching and also retrieve the correct icon for the active skin.

```
RewriteRule ^favicon.ico favicon.php [L]
```

Then in favicon.php return the correct version

```
<?php
    // add cache control headers here
    header('Content-type: image/x-icon');
    echo file_get_contents("path-to-skin-icon");
?>
```